# angular2 export to excel

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Im trying export to excel in angular but im getting error as " Cannot read property 'useBom' of undefined .Please help me to resolve this error"

```js
let options = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: '.',
      showLabels: false,
      headers: [],
      showTitle: true,
      title: 'asfasf',
      useBom: true,
      removeNewLines: true,
      keys: ['approved','age','name' ]
    };
   let data = [
      {
        name: "Test, 1",
        age: 13,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      }
    ];
  }
```

```html
<angular2csv [data]="data" filename="test.csv" [options]="options" ></angular2csv>`enter code here`
```

Comment: where are the `options` and `data` defined. Are they the fields of your component's class?

Comment: can you edit your question and show how does your component (the .ts file) look like (the one with the template which includes `<angular2csv>`)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `data` and `options` are not the class fields but some local variables in the method (I guess).
Looking at [the example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv).
You should have your `data` and `options` as the fields of your component's class so that the template can "see" them.

Comment: This only I tryed and am getting the error like "Cannot read property 'useBom' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

First, we use papaparse...
[enter link description here](https://www.papaparse.com/)

```
import { Papa } from 'ngx-papaparse';
import { exportCsv } from 'app/modules/core/functions/export-csv.function';

exportSummaryCsv() {
    const title = `Story Funnel Summary`;
    const summary = this._columns.map(column => ({
        'Stage': column.name,
        'Quantity': column.items.length
    }));
    const csv = this.csvParser.unparse(summary);
    exportCsv(title, csv);
}
```

then we create a blob and a link and insert a link into the DOM

```
export function exportCsv(filename: string, csv: string) {
    filename = `${filename.replace(/ /g, '_')}.csv`;

    const blob = new Blob([csv], {'type': 'text/csv;charset=utf8;'});
    const link = document.createElement('a');

    link.download = filename;
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

and then a button that fires all this...

Comment: Thank you for your Reply.How to add CSS property in export to excel in angular2

Comment: this is doing more than adding a CSS property.

Comment: ya but my requirement is to add colors to the header. So is there any property to do that. Or help me to add css in this.